# Filter Object By Keys

Tags: javascript, function, object, filter

Im learning higher order functions and having trouble quite often, this is pretty basic, perhaps I don't properly understand the parameters..Is there any reason why this solution would not work?

```
// Sample Input:
// [
//   { id: 42, name: 'Clojure' },
//   { id: 43, name: 'Haskell' },
//   { id: 44, name: 'Erlang' }
// ], 42

// Expected Output:
// { id: 42, name: 'Clojure' }

function findById (languages, id) {
  return languages.filter(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
};
```

Comment: it would assign the input to 42 if you have that `], 42` at the end

Comment: `filter` return an array of all the matched element or an empty one if nothing is matched. If you want to return only the first matched object then use `find` (which returns the first matched object or `null` if nothing is matched).

Comment: @Slai I think the commented bits are the parameters used to call the function `findById`: the array would be `languages` argument and `42` would be `id` argument.

Comment: I think in some case ,the type of Ids are different, so that sometime `"42" === 42` equal `false`. In this case, I suggest you parse all to integers before doing comparison.  Please read more about `===` if you're js starter :)!

Answer (score 2):

Well, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array. Which means, you would at least need to return the first item of it.

A better approach in this case would be to use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const input = [{
    id: 42,
    name: 'Clojure'
  },
  {
    id: 43,
    name: 'Haskell'
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    name: 'Erlang'
  }
];

function findById(languages, id) {
  return languages.find(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
};

console.log(findById(input, 42));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, only you need to access the 0th index of the result

**DEMO**

```js
var input = [
   { id: 42, name: 'Clojure' },
    { id: 43, name: 'Haskell' },
    { id: 44, name: 'Erlang' }
 ];

function findById (languages, id) {
  return languages.filter(function(element) {
    return element.id === id;
  });
};

console.log(findById(input,42)[0]);
```